# How can I make a contour plot from three columns in a dataframe? (other SO answers haven't worked)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I'm wanting to create a contour map (plot) based on the probability of a condition being met. So far I have three columns of equal length-- soil saturation (X), storm intensity (Y), and (Z) the probability of the condition being met (i.e. 0-1)

My X and Y data have a different number of unique values, such that each X value has a number of corresponding Y values from which to generate points in a typical scatterplot. I'd like to have contours of probability at location (X,Y) where hopefully I can illustrate a each contour as a decision boundary where the decision for a 1 is made above that probability value (e.g. 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, etc.).

I've so far tried a number of options and most of them start with np.meshgrid. I'll post some sample plots below. Is there anyway I can clean this up to just be a single line for each probability boundary?

Here is an example scatterplot I want to make contours from:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(18,5))
plt.scatter(sat_depth_test.loc[:,'soil sat'],sat_depth_test.loc[:,'storm depth'],c=probas[:,1],cmap='YlOrRd')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Prediction Boundary for Ksat = 0.00001, all other Base Case Parameterizations')
plt.xlabel('Antecedent Soil Saturation')
plt.ylabel('Storm Storm Depth (mm)')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim([5,150])
```

[scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qHM5.png)

I've also done something similar, but not with single lines showing the decision boundary:

```py
triang = tri.Triangulation(sat, storm)
interpolator = tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang, probdf['Prob'])
X,Y = np.meshgrid(sat,storm)
Z = interpolator(X, Y)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Prediction Boundary for Ksat = 0.00001, all other Base Case Parameterizations')
plt.xlabel('Antecedent Soil Saturation')
plt.ylabel('Storm Storm Depth (mm)')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim([5,150])
```

[contour plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0C7T.png)

I'm just feeling a little stuck here. Ideally, I'd like to have single lines showing contours for each 0.05 or 0.10 probability interval in place of a scatterplot.

It would be similar to this, but still cleaner:

[cleaner contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH5S7.png)

Ideally, I would like something like this: (borrowed from https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html)

[ideal plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwUGu.png)

I also apologize for not putting the actual plots on here. This is my first question on SO, and I'm having trouble finding out how to include them.

Thank you!

Comment: There are many many functions for that. Look for heatmap, matplotlib, contour plot, seaborn, pandas .... https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/tricontour_demo.html

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/tricontour_vs_griddata.html

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html

Comment: Hi, Joe--Thank you so much! I remember coming across all these in my search. Compared with the 'normal' contour function, what is the difference with that and the unstructured triangular grid? I understand the contour function takes inputs of a very specific shape, but the tricontour function does not. I'm assuming this makes it better suited for 1-D arrays?

Comment: Both of them are rather for 2d arrays, for 1d there is just a normal histogram. If 2d data is on a grid (regular) you can use a "normal" contour plot function. For scattered data you have two options. First, bin your data (regular grid) and use the mean, max, min, whatever of the bins and use a normal contour function. Second, use the triangular contour function. There the values between the data points (vertices) are calculated (interpolated) and shaded (colored) based on the values of the corners.

Comment: If you are interested in the details, this is how contour lines are calculated for a regular grid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares This is the idea for a triangle, which are used for random scattered data points: https://codeplea.com/triangular-interpolation or https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/barycentric-coordinates

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks, Joe!

Comment: OTHER ANSWER: https://plot.ly/python/contour-plots/. This got it for me.